# Flask: Json data appearing instead of html page

Tags: javascript, flask

I'm trying to create a flask app that converts between different units. When I submit the form containing the input and output units and the input value, the page just returns raw json data.

This is the code for sending the json data with the output value:

```
return jsonify({"output_value": output_value, "input-unit": input_unit, "output-unit": output_unit})
```

This is the js code for taking the json data and displaying it on the html page:

```
document.queryCommandValue("#form").onsubmit = () => {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const input_unit = document.querySelector("#input-unit").value;
    const ouput_unit = document.querySelector("#input-unit").value;
    request.open('POST', "/convert");

    request.onload = () => {
        // Take data from json request
        const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        const output_value = data.output_value;
        document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = output_value;
    }
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("output-value", output_value);
    formdata.append("input-unit", input_unit);
    formdata.append("output-unit", ouput_unit); 
    request.send(formdata);
    return false;
}
```

How would I properly return the html page with the output value displayed?

I'm trying to follow along with CS50's web programming course from 2018 if that helps.

Comment: It's `querySelector`, not `queryCommandValue`, which means your JS code does nothing and the HTML form is sent the regular way, with the browser displaying the result. You also need to fix your code regarding the values you're reading; otoh you should be able to simply send `new FormData(document.querySelector('#form'))`

Comment: Here's fixed example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/e8ansyrz/